# Context Oriented Runtime CDI Qualifiers (HK2, Guice)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, guice, hk2

I'm interested in using HK2 or Guice for a dependency injection framework.
I know of `@Named`, `@Qualifier`, and custom annotations etc.  But these are all compile-time.

I am looking for a facility to dynamically determine the desired concrete type based on runtime context and inject the correct implementation.

Is there something like that in HK2 or Guice or a recommended way of achieving this?

For example:

```
// I would want to turn this...
public final class Handler
{ 
  private final Session session;
   
  @Inject   
  public Handler(@Named("Database") final Session session)
  {
    this.session = session;
  }
  ...
}

// into something like this...
public final class Handler
{
  private final Session session;
    
  @Inject
  public Handler(final Session session)
  {
    this.session = session;
  }
}

// where "session" is injected based on some previous context value ("Database")
// or something to that effect.
```

Comment: In HK2, there is the concept of [`Factory`](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Factory.html)s, This allows you to determine the injected object at runtime. I don't work much with Guice, but I think their [FactoryProvider](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryProvider.html) is analogous.

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha, the HK2 Factory looks close to what I would want.  I'm not sure how I would get runtime information to the factory so it could decide the right implementation OR perhaps how to get runtime information to the injector to inject the right factory.

Comment: What information are you looking for?

Comment: Pretty much anything you can inject into the resource class, you can also inject into the factory. You could also inject the ContainerRequest. This will give you almost everything you need about the request.

Comment: If you do use a factory you can also inject an InstantiationService which can be used in the provide method to discover who is actually attempting to inject the service.  See https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InstantiationService.html

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a feature in [HK2](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/) called [Operations](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/operations.html) (link to docs).  It allows a user of HK2 to define custom scopes and manage them as "operations".  You can find a more detailed example of how to use the feature on HK2's github project: [operations example](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-hk2/tree/master/examples/operations).

This is a simplified example of how I ended up using this feature to inject things based on context or in this case "**scope**".

Here is some almost-working pseudo-code to demonstrate my usage:

```
// Create the custom scope annotation.
@Scope
@Proxiable(proxyForSameScope = false)
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BatchScope
{
  public static final BatchScope INSTANCE = new BatchScopeEnvoy();
}


final class BatchScopeEnvoy extends AnnotationLiteral<BatchScope> implements BatchScope
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 938233179310254573L;
}


// Create a context used by the HK2 operation feature.
@Singleton
public final class BatchScopeContext extends OperationContext<BatchScope>
{
  @Override
  public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope()
  {
    return BatchScope.class;
  }
}


// Create a class that holds your custom scope data/context.
public final class BatchScopeRuntime
{
   // ... Arbitrary runtime data here ...
     
     public SomeData getData()
     {
       return this.data;
     }
}


// Create a factory that serves up something you want to inject from a custom scope.
@Singleton
public final class DataFactory implements Factory<SomeData>
{
  private final OperationManager operations;

  @Inject
  public BatchInfoFactory(final OperationManager operations)
  {
    Sentinel.assertIsNotNull(operations);

    this.operations = operations;
  }


  // The @BatchScope on the provide() method indicates that objects returned 
  // from this factory are in the "BatchScope".
  @Override
  @BatchScope
  public IBatchInfo provide()
  {
    final OperationHandle handle = this.operations.getCurrentOperation(BatchScope.INSTANCE);
    final BatchScopeRuntime runtime = (BatchScopeRuntime)handle.getOperationData();

    return runtime.getData();
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose(final IBatchInfo instance)
  {
    // Do nothing.
  }
}


// Setup the injector.
public static ServiceLocator createInjector(final String name)
{
    final ServiceLocator injector = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create(name);

    ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(
      injector,
      new AbstractBinder()
      {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
           // This creates a "Singleton" factory that provides
           // "SomeData" instances at "BatchScope".
           bindFactory(DataFactory.class, Singleton.class)
            .to(SomeData.class)
            .in(BatchScope.class);
        }
      }
        
    return injector;
}


// Create a class that needs something in the custom scope.
public final class Foo
{
  @Inject
  public Foo(final SomeData data)
  {
    System.out.printf("I got: %s%n", data);
  }
}   


// Usage: how to manage the scopes using the operations feature.
final SomeData data = ... // get some data
final BatchScopeRuntime runtime = new BatchScopeRuntime(data); // Setup the runtime information.

// Create an operation handle for the custom scope and associate the custom data with it.
final ServiceLocator injector = createInjector("test");
ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(injector, BatchScopeContext.class, Foo.class);
final OperationManager operations = injector.getService(OperationManager.class);
final OperationHandle<BatchScope> batchScope = operations.createAndStartOperation(BatchScope.INSTANCE);

// Operation/scope is now associated with the current thread.           
batchScope.setOperationData(runtime);

// Foo will now be injected with: "data" from above.
final Foo foo = injector.getService(Foo.class);

// Do some work...

// Close the operation (make it go out of scope) on the current thread.
batchScope.closeOperation();
```

Comment: Operations are really nice if your usage pattern fits.  It's the easiest way to make your own custom contexts